# How to put a bunch of different types of documents into a single Word doc?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, documents, microsoft-word-2010, ole

I am working on a long document that will have to include JPEGs, certain pages of PDF docs, bits and pieces from various Excel spreadsheets.  I need all this to end up in a Word document.

I suppose I can print out each piece separately, then scan them all, but I won't end up with an editable document (the PDF part does not need to be editable).

I seem to remember doing something similar back in the Windows 3.1 days with Object Linking and Embedding. How does one do it these days with Word 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can cut and paste JPEGs and Excel spreadsheets right into Word.

PDFs are a different story, as you cant import them directly.  You can cut and paste their text and images into Word, but they wont retain their original formatting -- however, that might not be an issue for you.  You can use a screen cap program to capture the PDF and paste the pages as images in Word.  There are even some programs that will convert PDF files to Word documents, but they never seem to hold their formatting properly -- again you can just format them in Word as necessary.

Comment: I remember receiving some word docs with PDF files embedded in them as icons so they opened in your PDF reader but I don't know how to do the embedding in office 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You can cut-n-paste or just drag-n-drop most objects onto a Word document and Word will help you import them as you want.

Here's some basic embedding steps for 2007/2010 that will help you control it a little more as you go:

1. Open a Microsoft Word document.
2. Place your cursor where you want to insert an embedded object.
3. Click the "Insert" tab. Click "Object" in the "Text" group.
4. Click the "Create from file" tab to embed an existing object. Click "Browse" to select the file from your computer. Uncheck the "Link to file" box. Click "OK."
5. Click the "Microsoft Office Button" or "File" tab. Click "Save" to save the Word document.

Source: [How to Embed Objects in MS Word](http://www.ehow.com/how_6955510_embed-objects-ms-word.html)